# Pandas - reorder rows based on group and condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dataframes, each one having a list of players, by position (Forwards, Defenders and Goalkeepers):

```
FWD_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Keno','Pepê','Rhuan','Léo Natel','Pedro Raul','Wesley'],
                        'team':['Atlético-MG','Grêmio','Botafogo','Corinthians','Botafogo','Palmeiras'],
                        'adversary':['Fluminense','Botafogo','Grêmio','Athlético-PR','Grêmio','Coritiba'], 
                         'position':['FWD', 'FWD', 'FWD', 'FWD', 'FWD', 'FWD'],
                         'open_price':[15.75, 14.05, 3.51, 5.83, 5.92, 4.25]})


MID_df = pd.DataFrame({'apelido':['Everton Ribeiro','Thiago Galhardo','Thiago Neves','Mateus Vital','Dodi','Zé Gabriel'],
                       'clube':['Flamengo','Internacional','Sport','Corinthians','Fluminense', 'Internacional'],
                       'adversário':['Bragantino','Sport','Internacional','Athlético-PR','Atlético-MG','Sport'],  
                       'posicao':['MID', 'MID', 'MID','MID', 'MID', 'MID'],
                       'preco_open':[10.82, 6.46, 4.96, 8.20, 5.29, 7.88]}).sort_values('preco_open', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).copy()


WING_df = pd.DataFrame({'apelido':['Renê','Abner Vinícius','Marcos Rocha','Victor Luis','Fagner','Ramon'],
                       'clube':['Flamengo','Athlético-PR','Palmeiras','Botafogo','Corinthians', 'Flamengo'],
                       'adversário':['Bragantino','Corinthians','Coritiba','Grêmio','Athlético-PR','Bragantino'],  
                       'posicao':['WING', 'WING', 'WING','WING', 'WING', 'WING'],
                       'preco_open':[10.82, 6.46, 4.96, 8.20, 5.29, 7.88]}).sort_values('preco_open', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).copy()

DEF_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Pedro Geromel','Felipe Melo','Pedro Henrique','Réver','Thiago Heleno','Lucas Veríssimo'],
                       'team':['Grêmio','Palmeiras','Athlético-PR','Atlético-MG','Athlético-PR', 'Santos'],
                       'adversary':['Botafogo','Coritiba','Corinthians','Fluminense','Corinthians','Atlético-GO'],  
                       'position':['DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF','DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF'],
                       'open_price':[10.82, 6.46, 4.96, 8.20, 5.29, 7.88]})

GKP_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Jandrei','Jean','Muriel','Diego Cavalieri','Marcelo Lomba','Luan Polli'],
                       'team':['Athlético-PR','Atlético-GO','Fluminense','Botafogo','Internacional', 'Sport'],
                       'adversary':['Corinthians','Santos','Atlético-MG','Grêmio','Sport','Internacional'], 
                       'position':['GKP', 'GKP', 'GKP','GKP', 'GKP', 'GKP'],
                       'open_price':[8.73, 8.88, 5.66, 5.70, 10.62, 4.00]})
```

---

Then I create a pool for those selected players, like so:

```
dfs = [FWD_df, DEF_df, GKP_df]

pool = pd.concat(dfs)

print (pool)
```

which prints:

```
              name           team      adversary position  open_price
0             Keno    Atlético-MG     Fluminense      FWD       15.75
1             Pepê         Grêmio       Botafogo      FWD       14.05
2            Rhuan       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        3.51
3        Léo Natel    Corinthians   Athlético-PR      FWD        5.83
4       Pedro Raul       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        5.92
5           Wesley      Palmeiras       Coritiba      FWD        4.25
0    Pedro Geromel         Grêmio       Botafogo      DEF       10.82
1      Felipe Melo      Palmeiras       Coritiba      DEF        6.46
2   Pedro Henrique   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      DEF        4.96
3            Réver    Atlético-MG     Fluminense      DEF        8.20
4    Thiago Heleno   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      DEF        5.29
5  Lucas Veríssimo         Santos    Atlético-GO      DEF        7.88
0          Jandrei   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      GKP        8.73
1             Jean    Atlético-GO         Santos      GKP        8.88
2           Muriel     Fluminense    Atlético-MG      GKP        5.66
3  Diego Cavalieri       Botafogo         Grêmio      GKP        5.70
4    Marcelo Lomba  Internacional          Sport      GKP       10.62
5       Luan Polli          Sport  Internacional      GKP        4.00
```

---

**RULE**:

The thing is I cannot have, *from the top 3 forwards*, a player facing *any of the top 2 defenders* nor the *top 1 goalkeeper*, ie, if he is his next 'adversary', like so:

```
             name           team          adversary position  open_price
2            Rhuan       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        3.51
...
0    Pedro Geromel         Grêmio       Botafogo      DEF       10.82
```

---

When this happens I need to keep the most valuable player (highest 'open_price') on its row position and move the cheapest one to its last grouped row index.

In the case above the defender costs more, so he stays where he is and we move the FWD down to last index on its position:

```
             name           team       adversary position  open_price
0             Keno    Atlético-MG     Fluminense      FWD       15.75
1             Pepê         Grêmio       Botafogo      FWD       14.05
2        Léo Natel    Corinthians   Athlético-PR      FWD        5.83
3       Pedro Raul       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        5.92
4           Wesley      Palmeiras       Coritiba      FWD        4.25
5            Rhuan       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        3.51 <---- was index 2, now 5
0    Pedro Geromel         Grêmio       Botafogo      DEF       10.82
1      Felipe Melo      Palmeiras       Coritiba      DEF        6.46
2   Pedro Henrique   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      DEF        4.96
3            Réver    Atlético-MG     Fluminense      DEF        8.20
4    Thiago Heleno   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      DEF        5.29
5  Lucas Veríssimo         Santos    Atlético-GO      DEF        7.88
0          Jandrei   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      GKP        8.73
1             Jean    Atlético-GO         Santos      GKP        8.88
2           Muriel     Fluminense    Atlético-MG      GKP        5.66
3  Diego Cavalieri       Botafogo         Grêmio      GKP        5.70
4    Marcelo Lomba  Internacional          Sport      GKP       10.62
5       Luan Polli          Sport  Internacional      GKP        4.00
```

---

But by doing so, now we have a Forward in the top 3 that will face a goalkeeper, which is also forbidden by the RULE:

```
             name            team      adversary position  open_price
2        Léo Natel    Corinthians   Athlético-PR      FWD        5.83
...
0          Jandrei   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      GKP        8.73
```

And since the goalkeeper costs more than the forward, he stays where he is and we move the forward down, like so:

```
             name           team       adversary position  open_price
0             Keno    Atlético-MG     Fluminense      FWD       15.75
1             Pepê         Grêmio       Botafogo      FWD       14.05
2       Pedro Raul       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        5.92
3           Wesley      Palmeiras       Coritiba      FWD        4.25
4            Rhuan       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        3.51 <---- was index 5, now 4
5        Léo Natel    Corinthians   Athlético-PR      FWD        5.83 <---- was index 2, now 5
0    Pedro Geromel         Grêmio       Botafogo      DEF       10.82
1      Felipe Melo      Palmeiras       Coritiba      DEF        6.46
2   Pedro Henrique   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      DEF        4.96
3            Réver    Atlético-MG     Fluminense      DEF        8.20
4    Thiago Heleno   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      DEF        5.29
5  Lucas Veríssimo         Santos    Atlético-GO      DEF        7.88
0          Jandrei   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      GKP        8.73
1             Jean    Atlético-GO         Santos      GKP        8.88
2           Muriel     Fluminense    Atlético-MG      GKP        5.66
3  Diego Cavalieri       Botafogo         Grêmio      GKP        5.70
4    Marcelo Lomba  Internacional          Sport      GKP       10.62
5       Luan Polli          Sport  Internacional      GKP        4.00
```

And again we will have to do this once more:

```
             name           team       adversary position  open_price
0             Keno    Atlético-MG     Fluminense      FWD       15.75
1             Pepê         Grêmio       Botafogo      FWD       14.05
2           Wesley      Palmeiras       Coritiba      FWD        4.25 <---- was index 3, now 2
3            Rhuan       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        3.51 <---- was index 4, now 3
4        Léo Natel    Corinthians   Athlético-PR      FWD        5.83 <---- was index 5, now 4
5       Pedro Raul       Botafogo         Grêmio      FWD        5.92 <---- was index 3, now 5
0    Pedro Geromel         Grêmio       Botafogo      DEF       10.82
1      Felipe Melo      Palmeiras       Coritiba      DEF        6.46
2   Pedro Henrique   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      DEF        4.96
3            Réver    Atlético-MG     Fluminense      DEF        8.20
4    Thiago Heleno   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      DEF        5.29
5  Lucas Veríssimo         Santos    Atlético-GO      DEF        7.88
0          Jandrei   Athlético-PR    Corinthians      GKP        8.73
1             Jean    Atlético-GO         Santos      GKP        8.88
2           Muriel     Fluminense    Atlético-MG      GKP        5.66
3  Diego Cavalieri       Botafogo         Grêmio      GKP        5.70
4    Marcelo Lomba  Internacional          Sport      GKP       10.62
5       Luan Polli          Sport  Internacional      GKP        4.00
```

---

Until we end up with the dataframe above, ie the final pool.

---

How do I do this conditional re ordering of rows? Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Do you want a custom sort function on open_price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in which you need to find an equilibrium based on constraints.

I propose here a solution in which we do not work with `pandas`, but rather pure python lists because pandas' overhead would only slow the solution down.

First of all, there's an obvious possiblity of an infinite loop. As such, you have to keep track of past arrangement configurations so as to know when you have made a circle and began a loop.

I have created a custom error `InfeasableError` (for readability) which is raised whenever this happens. The rest of the code should be straightforward.

#### `Setup`

```
class InfeasableError(Exception):
  pass

# These are the positions on the lists for team, adv and prices.
TEAM_POS = 2
ADVERSARY_POS = 3
PRICE_POS = 5

fwd = FWD_df.reset_index().values.tolist()
dfs = DEF_df.reset_index().values.tolist()
gkp = GKP_df.reset_index().values.tolist()
mid = MID_df.reset_index().values.tolist()
wig = WING_df.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

---

Now, the equilibrium-finding function:

```
def find_equilibrium(fwd, dfs, gkp, mid, wig, configs):
''' Finds an equilibrium for forward, defense and goalkeeper players.
'''

  initial_config = get_config(fwd, dfs, gkp) # Initial configuration

  # Below is the logic for FWD-DEF equilibria.

  for i, fwd_player in enumerate(fwd[:3]):
    for j, def_player in enumerate(dfs[:2]):
      if fwd_player[ADVERSARY_POS] == def_player[TEAM_POS]:
        if fwd_player[PRICE_POS] < def_player[PRICE_POS]:
          del fwd[i]
          fwd.append(fwd_player)
        else:
          del dfs[j]
          dfs.append(def_player)

  # Below is the logic for FWD-GKP equilibria.

  gkp_player = gkp[0]
  for i, fwd_player in enumerate(fwd[:3]):
    if fwd_player[ADVERSARY_POS] == gkp_player[TEAM_POS]:
      if fwd_player[PRICE_POS] < gkp_player[PRICE_POS]:
        del fwd[i]
        fwd.append(fwd_player)
      else:
        del gkp[0]
        gkp.append(gkp_player)
  
  final_config = get_config(fwd, dfs, gkp)
  if initial_config == final_config:
    # This means nothing changed. Equilibrium found!
    return [*fwd, *dfs, *gkp]

  if final_config in configs: 
    raise InfeasableError("There's no solution for an equilibrium.")

  configs.append(final_config)
  return find_equilibrium(fwd, dfs, gkp, mid, wig, configs)

def get_config(fwd, dfs, gkp):
  ''' Returns an ordered configuration of integers. 
      Each integer represents a unique player, and each sequence represents
      a specific configuration of how these players are arranged.
  '''
  return (fwd[0][0], fwd[1][0], fwd[2][0], dfs[0][0], dfs[1][0], gkp[0][0])

solution = find_equilibrium(fwd, dfs, gkp, mid, wig, [])
```

---

The solution comes ready to be imported into pandas, if you need it:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(solution)
```

---

```
    0                1              2              3    4      5
0   0             Keno    Atlético-MG     Fluminense  FWD  15.75
1   1             Pepê         Grêmio       Botafogo  FWD  14.05
2   5           Wesley      Palmeiras       Coritiba  FWD   4.25
3   2            Rhuan       Botafogo         Grêmio  FWD   3.51
4   3        Léo Natel    Corinthians   Athlético-PR  FWD   5.83
5   4       Pedro Raul       Botafogo         Grêmio  FWD   5.92
6   0    Pedro Geromel         Grêmio       Botafogo  DEF  10.82
7   1      Felipe Melo      Palmeiras       Coritiba  DEF   6.46
8   2   Pedro Henrique   Athlético-PR    Corinthians  DEF   4.96
9   3            Réver    Atlético-MG     Fluminense  DEF   8.20
10  4    Thiago Heleno   Athlético-PR    Corinthians  DEF   5.29
11  5  Lucas Veríssimo         Santos    Atlético-GO  DEF   7.88
12  0          Jandrei   Athlético-PR    Corinthians  GKP   8.73
13  1             Jean    Atlético-GO         Santos  GKP   8.88
14  2           Muriel     Fluminense    Atlético-MG  GKP   5.66
15  3  Diego Cavalieri       Botafogo         Grêmio  GKP   5.70
16  4    Marcelo Lomba  Internacional          Sport  GKP  10.62
17  5       Luan Polli          Sport  Internacional  GKP   4.00
```

Comment: this is a BRILLIANT solution. If you don't mind, I have added all positions, with two extra dataframes -midfielders and wings (to which dthe constraints do not apply). could you account their input into find equilibrium() as well, to be so kind, only for completeness sake? this way I can output the whole picture

Comment: @8-BitBorges Sure. I've added `mid` and `wig` to the arguments and method call. In case you need to add constraints to those as well, you can always follow the structure for `fwd-dfs` and `fwd-gkp` !

Comment: obrigado Rafael. vi que você também é brasileiro. genial, cara.